# Android : DatePicker dropdown like Spinner

Tags: android, android-datepicker

My designers would like to show a `DatePicker` which looks like a dropdown-list: 
[image]

Is it a good idea to use `Spinner` to implement the same? Would I have to write my own logic to take care of how many days fall in which months, leap years etc.?

Or is there any way to customise the Android `DatePicker` or any other widget to achieve this functionality wherein I don't have to take care of writing logic for handling the dates?

Is the practice recommended at all?

Comment: You want them to be in different fields??

Comment: better to use native `DatePicker` component, check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html and this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Comment: No,  you can't get same to same UI in Android

Comment: @MohammadZarei The final user-input will be sent to the server as a timestamp (type Long). So even though the UI for all 3 fields needs to be separate drop downs, the final value can be a single field of Calendar / Long format.

Comment: there is a reason why the datepicker looks another way in Android. Everybody will recommend you to use default datepicker. Your approach is bad, and will be not comfortable for users. Do you really want users to hate you?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Actually I completely agree with you. The thing is, we used to have a normal datepicker before but users are 'clicking' on it, rather than scrolling and our app drop-off is quite high at that screen, so we thought we'd redesign and try it this way instead. Maybe our user-base is more used to the web-way-of-things. Not sure though..

Comment: @Mallika scrolling option is available in default date-picker so go for that

Comment: make it as a dialog. Dialog is most common way to select date. I think that in the dialog it will look more obvious what to do with it.

Comment: @Mallika I feel you should stick to the default one. Android's date picker is self explanatory. This ain't tough to understand.

Comment: @Mallika Well, you may try datePickerMode="calendar"

Comment: can you share your code because i need same like this, i have searched to much but not get the solution?

Comment: @Mallika finally what you did? Default or the one your asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers.

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
```

In your Activity;

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerBuilder dpb = new DatePickerBuilder()
                .setFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager())
                .setStyleResId(R.style.BetterPickersDialogFragment)
                .setYearOptional(true);
        dpb.show();
    }
});
```

Otherwise: many more opensource libraries;
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=rating

Comment: None of these have exactly what I had needed, but we checked out the different libraries, modified our design and used a combination of those. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the spinner-style date picker, you can set the datePickerMode attribute of DatePicker to spinner.

```
<DatePicker
...
android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Comment: @Mallika I feel this answer serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can set style in Programmer.

```
 etDOB.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
    });
```